# Return individual days opening hours from foursquare venue endpoint

Tags: javascript, foursquare

The foursquare api returns the following, located at data.response.venue.hours, for the venue opening hours at:

```
hours: {
    status: "Closed until Noon",
    isOpen: false
    timeframes: [
        {
            days: "Mon–Wed",
            open: [
                {
                    renderedTime: "Noon–11:00 PM"
                }
            ],
                segments: [ ]
        },
        {
            days: "Thu",
            includesToday: true,
            open: [
                {
                    renderedTime: "Noon–Midnight"
                }
            ]
                segments: [ ]
        },
        {
            days: "Fri–Sat",
            open: [
                {
                    renderedTime: "11:00 AM–1:00 AM"
                }
            ]
                segments: [ ]
        },
        {
            days: "Sun",
            open: [
                {
                    renderedTime: "Noon–10:30 PM"
                }
            ]
                segments: [ ]
        },
    ]
}
```

The group of days varies from venue to venue, i.e. some might have Mon-Tue, Wed-Sat, Sun or another variation instead of the above.

I'm looking to sort this information so that I can return the opening hours for individual days, i.e. call Monday on it's own. My javascript knowledge isn't that great so where to start would be good.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

For getting venue hours, you can use the venues/VENUE_ID/hours endpoint, which has a more machine-friendly result

```
  hours: {
    timeframes: [
      {
        days: [
          1
          2
          3
          4
          5
          6
          7
        ],
        includesToday: true,
        open: [
          {
            start: "0600",
            end: "2000"
          }
        ],
        segments: [ ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

This is a simplified case where all 7 days have the same open segment, but in other cases you should be able to iterate through timeframes and get each day's open array.

```
var Mon;
if (timeframes[j].days.indexOf(i) != -1) {
  Mon = timeframes[j].open;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a mapping object describing what days match with the particular opening times:

```
var diff = {
  mon: 'Mon–Wed',
  tue: 'Mon–Wed',
  wed: 'Mon–Wed',
  thu: 'Thu',
  fri: 'Fri-Sat',
  sat: 'Fri-Sat'
};
```

Then, instead of sorting the data I would use `filter` to pull out the relevant result from the data using the mapping object:

```
function getOpeningTimes(day) {
  var arr = hours.timeframes.filter(function (el) {

    // return the match where the value of the property
    // in the mapping object that matches the search equals the
    // days property in the current object in the data.
    return diff[day] === el.days;
  });
  return arr[0].open[0].renderedTime;
}

console.log(getOpeningTimes('mon')); // Noon–11:00 PM
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/hcdGz/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, not sure that the first part will suit my needs though because, for example, Monday doesn't necessarily come in Mon-Wed, the api could return something like Mon-Thu or Sun-Tue. I'll give the second part a shot once i've managed to figure out the days.